# Two x-axis scales on one R plot

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to create a plot that shows two different time scales on the x-axis.  The problem is that the two time scales have a complicated relationship.

I would like to show weather data by the day of year and by the thermal units.  Thermal units are the accumulation of the mean temperatures of each day.  Some days we get a lot of thermal units, some days not so many.  I fit a spline to the relationship between day of year and thermal units and used that to predict thermal unit values for each day.  So I do have a nice dataset with the following headers: day of year (day), thermal units (gdd), temperature (temp), precipitation (precip).

I created the following figure (may have to open in new window): [image: Wrong Scale]

with this code:

```
pdf(file="Climate 2010.pdf", family="Times")
par(mar = c(5,4,4,4) + 0.3)

plot(cobs10$day, cobs10$precip, col="white", type="h", yaxt="n", xaxt="n", ylab="",      
xlab="")
axis(side=3, col="black", labels=FALSE) 
at = axTicks(3)
mtext(side = 3, text = at, at = at, col="black", line = 1, las=0)
mtext("Day of Year", side=3, las=0, line = 3)

par(new=TRUE)
plot(cobs10$gdd, cobs10$temp, type="l", col="red", yaxt="n", ylab="", xlab="Thermal    
Units")
axis(side=2, col='red', labels=FALSE)
at= axTicks(2)
mtext(side=2, text= at, at = at, col = "red", line = 1, las=0)
mtext("Temperature (C)", side=2, las=0, line=3)

par(new=TRUE)
plot(cobs10$gdd, cobs10$precip, type="h", col="blue", yaxt="n", xaxt="n", ylab="",   
xlab="")
axis(side=4, col='blue', labels=FALSE)
at = axTicks(4)
mtext(side = 4, text = at, at = at, col = "blue", line = 1,las=0)
mtext("Precipitation (cm)", side=4, las=0, line = 3)

dev.off()
```

This is exactly what I want, but I realized the x-axis scales are linear here, and they should not be. I put the top x-axis in by making my precipitation data white and writing over it.  See what happens when I make it green:

[image: Obviously wrong scales]

It's obvious things don't match up.  **So how can I make the two axes in scale with eachother?**

Here's the little dataframe I have been using where the time units are matched up by predicting:
[cobs10.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ysoiut7ma5y8q30/cobs10.txt). "gdd" is thermal units

EDIT: Here is some new code that doesn't use par(new=TRUE):

```
par(mar = c(5,4,4,4) + 0.3)
plot(cobs10$gdd, cobs10$temp, type="l", col="red", yaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="",     
ylim=c(-25, 30))
lines(cobs10$gdd, cobs10$precip, type="h", col="blue", yaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="")

axis(side=3, col="black", at=cobs10$gdd, labels=cobs10$day) 
want<-(c(1, 130, 150, 170, 190, 210, 230, 250, 270, 360))
mtext(side = 3, text = want, at = want, col="black", line = 1, las=0)
mtext("Day of Year", side=3, las=0, line = 3)

axis(side=2, col='red', labels=FALSE)
at= axTicks(2)
mtext(side=2, text= at, at = at, col = "red", line = 1, las=0)
mtext("Temperature (C)", side=2, las=0, line=3)

axis(side=4, col='blue', labels=FALSE)
at = axTicks(4)
mtext(side = 4, text = at, at = at, col = "blue", line = 1,las=0)
mtext("Precipitation (cm)", side=4, las=0, line = 3)
```

Comment: Not sure why those images don't show up right away, but you can see them if you open them in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost never a good idea to use `par(new=TRUE)`, it causes more problems than it solves.

You should decide which x axis units you want to use, days or thermal units and create the initial graph using that unit, then use functions like `points` or `lines` to add any additional points or lines to the existing graph using the existing units.  You can then use the `axis` function to add another axis, use the original units for the `at` argument, but then the conversion to the other units for the labels (you need to decide if you want the locations of the ticks to match the original units, or be in locations that give pretty values for the converted units).

Comment: I follow you, but it looks weird.  The tick mark labels appear out of order, 108 coming after 300 and such.

Comment: Alright, @Greg, I've almost got it figured out, but I want to reduce the number of tick marks shown on an x-axis.  Since the at> and labels> arguments are occupied, I'm not sure how to change the number of tick marks.  Using xaxp> just writes over what I already have.

Comment: @Nazar, just pass shorter vectors to `at` and `labels` that only include the tick locations that you want.

Comment: I'm sorry to be so dense, but it is just not working for me.  If I use any vectors other than straight out of my dataframe, they don't match up properly or don't span the whole axis.  If you find the time, could you give me an example of what the code would look like?

Comment: @Nazer, can you provide the data or some data similar to work with?

Comment: there is a small text file posted above (cobs10.txt).  I posted the new code I have been trying.  They should work well together and you should be able to see what problems I have been having.  The two x-axis scales look good together, there are just too many tick marks.  My attempt to have fewer tick marks and labels doesn't work.